# Is there any free Movie listing and showtime API's?

Tags: api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a movie showtime api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439857/is-there-a-movie-showtime-api)

I'm creating a site that needs to be able to list Movie listings with showtimes. I need an API where I can search for different criteria, such as zip code, genre, and other parameters related to movie listings.

Is there any free Movie listing and showtime API's?

If there are no quality free API's for that, are there any good API's that are commercially licensed?

I found some mention to the Fandango API on the web, but I have not been able to find any documentation relating to it. Does anyone know where I can find that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fandango provides a number of RSS feeds that you may be able to use to accomplish your task:

http://www.fandango.com/rss/moviefeed

Some examples on Yahoo Pipes:

- http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=Gle_P_Hc3RGo3H61LXO0Kg
- http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=f42d41612b2a890122504f919b2705e1

This also looks promising, but I haven't tested it:

http://www.ignyte.com/webservices/ignyte.whatsshowing.webservice/moviefunctions.asmx