# movie showtimes and map from Google API

Tags: google-api

When I do a search on google for a particular movie title, it brings up the showtimes and theater location near me. I was wondering if I can get this data in an xml format so I can use it?

http://www.google.com/movies?hl=en&q=movie_name

The other question is that from google map api. Is it possible to get the map of the theaters that is currently playing movie X at city/zipcode Y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first question is answered at [Is there a movie showtime api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439857/is-there-a-movie-showtime-api)

And yes you can use the google maps API to display the locations of theaters on the map. But you'll need to obtain those locations yourself. Theres nothing in the maps API like getMovieTheaters().

Comment: I don't see any xml object when I do view source?

Comment: Yeah thats correct because from that thread the basic consensus is there is no free API. The "secret" Yahoo API also got shutdown. A more recent question also acknowledged that does not seem to be any free APIs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937838/movie-showtimes-api. TMS Data is a non-free API you can use http://www.tmsdatadirect.com/

Answer (score 0):

See the TMS API:

http://developer.tmsapi.com/docs/read/Home

You can make 50 calls per day for free.

Updated Link:
http://developer.tmsapi.com/docs/data_v1_1/Movies/

Comment: available for US and Canada only