# Google API Movie Showtimes Documentation

Tags: xml, web-services, movie

where can I see the Google API [movie showtimes](http://www.google.com/movies) documentation please ?

On an other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439857/is-there-a-movie-showtime-api) I found this :

> http://www.google.com/ig/api?movies=poznan&theater=rialto&start=2&date=3&time=1
>
> movies=poznan
>
> theater=rialto
>
> date=0 <0-today; 1-tomorrow; 2-day after tomorrow ....>
>
> time=1  <1-morning, 2 afternoon ......, 5 all day>
>
> start=0 <0-show list from the first element, 2-show list from the
>   second element ...>

I would like to know the exhaustive list of the url parameters.

Where can I find all these informations please ?

Comment: `Google Showtimes was discontinued on November 1, 2016` https://www.google.com/movies/about/

Answer (score 7):

The Google's movie API is not official. It was developed for iGoogle developers and since it has closed, this particular API may not work. You can either do screen scraping from [Google's movie](http://www.google.com/movies)  OR use API provided by other sites. I found a site which provides feeds for Movies - [Fandango](http://www.fandango.com/rss/moviefeed). Here is an example RSS feed for movies near ZIP 90210 - http://www.fandango.com/rss/moviesnearme_90210.rss.

Comment: I would caution folks against scraping from Google's movie listing webpages as your server is very likely to get flagged.

Comment: Do you know if its against fandango policy to scrape this RSS feed?

Comment: @jlane09 Their page on [RSS Feeds](http://www.fandango.com/rss/moviefeed) encourages us to use it on our website as it reads: 

> Stay up to date on the latest movie releases, entertainment news and all things movies with Fandango RSS feeds. Be a movie insider by using Fandango RSS feeds to stay in the know, or create an entertainment destination right on your website! Enhance your site with exclusive Fandango content today.

Comment: The Fandango rss feed seems to be returning movies that aren't out yet. Is there a way to limit to only movies that are already out?