# PHP server hitting https://www.google.com/movies gets no results

Tags: php, search, search-engine, file-get-contents, movies

If you go to https://www.google.com/movies?near=02215&q=revenant you will clearly get results returned to you that can be parsed. However, when I upload a small script to my server like:

```
<?php 

$string = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/movies?near=02215&q=revenant");

echo $string;

?>
```

The output of the results is something along the lines of "No results found"

Any ideas?

Comment: When I tested that URL in Chrome, I got "No hits".

Comment: `Your query - revenant - did not match any movie reviews, showtimes or theaters.` - looks like it's the URL you're hitting

Comment: I get this http://i.imgur.com/f6291fa.png

Comment: The problem still stands though, no matter WHAT the query, it never returns results when done from the server

Comment: @MagnusEriksson [I got hits](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ3xY.png)

Comment: @jlane09 It's very possible that Google is blocking scraping attempts.

Comment: I need to change the location to my zip code to get results. Then it also adds a `&stok=xxxxx` to the URL. When removing the `&stok=xxxx` from the URL i get no result anymore

Comment: Seem to be some type of CSRF-token or something.

Comment: @jlane09 Looks like you are not the first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379555/google-api-movie-showtimes-documentation

Comment: I'm in Costa Rica ~ I get no results for the original query, but I do get results for https://www.google.com/movies?near=14139&q=daddy which is upstate NY.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus how would they block that? How would they know? Also, that question was similar but didn't seem to be having the issues I am. It was asking for documentation. On that note, does anyone know what happens if your server gets "flagged" by google

Answer (score 1):

Google is picky about who they send HTTP responses to, tell them you're a browser, see if this works:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => "GET",
        'header' => "" .
            "Accept: text/html" . "\r\n" .
            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0" . "\r\n"
    )
));

$string = file_get_contents( "https://www.google.com/movies?near=02215&q=revenant", false, $context );
```

Comment: @jlane09 damn, i was getting blank results at first, but worked for me after I added the headers. Try using CURL.

Comment: maybe my server has already been put on some list, but I will try with curl too